# node.js require files globally

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem which i would like to get help with here on stackoverflow.

In my node.js project i have a init.js file which i want to do the following

pseudo code

```
var variable = require(folder/file).name; (of exported module)
var variable2 = reuire(folder2/file2).name; (of exported module)
variable2.init();
```

in my init function i am trying to use my var (which in this dummy case) called variable. My catch returns the error that the var called variables is not found. i found that if i use global.variable = require.... then the stuff would work. I though doubt that this is a good way to work in node.js

Why do i want to do it this way? because in my variable2 functions i require other stuff which my variable1 functions is needed (and my init.js is on super top in these layers).

Any tips or help on how to either fix this or structure things better ?

Comment: Don't show pseudo code. Show us the real code so we can understand your question and what's wrong. And if you can show the error output also.

Comment: Jackowski

It's as simple as the the pseudo code

i mean in my init.js file i require all stuff but lower down in the hierarchy i am not able to access any of my functions (even though they seem to be in a global scope)

Answer (score 2):

You should require the module inside the module where you need it. In your case the line `var variable = require(folder/file);` should be inside `folder2/file2` and not your `init.js` file.

Comment: And if i would need it many levels down, should i require it in each given file then ?

Comment: my reason to put it in init.js is to be able to use it in many other files, it seems that making it global like global.variable = require... is the only thing that works

Comment: You should use `require` in every file where you need it. Stay away from the global scope which will cause even more headache